# How to get the sub part of xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

I have the following xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school>
    <student>
        <firstname name="ankush">
            <test>sample </test>  //......here can be more sub nodes

        </firstname>
        <lastname>thakur</lastname>
        <email>beingjavaguy.gmail.com</email>
        <phone>7678767656</phone>
        <address>
          <houseNo> </houseNo>
          <street> </street>
          <city> </city>
          <pincode> </pincode>
        </address>
    </student>
</school>
```

from the above xml file I want to get the  node as string like below

```
<address>
      <houseNo> </houseNo>
      <street> </street>
      <city> </city>
      <pincode> </pincode>
    </address>
```

The above address xml node will be converted as a json to use in my application.

I tried DOM, SAX parser but they will be used in only getting each node by node not the part of xml file.

Since my xml file is some what large, I prefer to use XMLStreamReader.

Could any body tell me, how to get the part of the xml file as a string?

Comment: You mean you need to get perticular parent node and its child nodes  from the big xml file????

Comment: Yes right @KishanCS

Comment: Please can you clarify what you think it's large (to make  suggesting a solution easier)

Comment: I mean the xml file is quite large may be in MB's

Comment: So may be in MB, not 20MB+

Answer (score 0):

Try it with jsoup. Example :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
// add
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class JsoupTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{                  
        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\eritrean\\Desktop\\test.xml");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input,"UTF-8");
        //select all address tags; returns a list of Elements
        Elements addresses = doc.getElementsByTag("address");
        for(Element address : addresses){
            System.out.println(address);
            System.out.println("------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Eritrean, thanks for the reply, here i want to get address field of each student in the xml file. how to do looping?

Comment: I have edited my answer. First get all "adress"-Elements by their tag name and loop through the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tools for parsing xml in an simple way; JaxB, dom4j, jsoup...  to name but a few. They all have strengths and weaknesses.

The import thing to consider when choosing which technology to use is what do you actually need now and how much flexibility are you likely to need.

So for food you, you need to access the address for each student (I am assuming your xml file could contain multiple students).

Do you only need the address or do you need more?
What are you needing to do with the address, do you need it in a particular structure for processing?
Do you have any existing xml processing in the application? (I don't like introducing two techs which do the same thing)

If you just want to find data as Strings then Jsoup or Dom4j are perfect (like the example written by Eritrean), However if you require your data to be in more of an OO structure, then JaxB could be beneficial.

JaxB basically converts xml to a specified POJO structure (anotated with javax.xml.bind.annotation anotations), therefore your data is automatically nicely encapsulated.

you could use:

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(documentXml)));
org.w3c.dom.Node rootNode = xmlDocument.getFirstChild();
// then get by tag name
```

Comment: Can we do this with XMLInputFactory which is from Java API, because I am hesitating to introduce one more new library

Comment: I like the approach on not adding libraries unless you need them. I have never directly used XMLInputFactory and currently I do not have time to investigate it.

I would recommend using JaxB because I think it is a very good solution or the w3c implementation (native to java)

Comment: I have added an example of java's w3c implementation.